# Verify language that i found of this automata

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

Sorry for my bad english.

Automata:

[image]

My answer:
$$L = \{0^n, 0^n1X \mid n = 1,2,3\dots\}$$

X is any strings that is not empty.

Comment: I edited it but I don't know what you meant by 0^n1X. Did you mean $0^n 1_X$?

Comment: Thanks @John Doe for edited my post, first time here, i am learning how to use math symbol on this forum.Yes it's $0^n1X$ , $0^n$ follow by 1 follow by X

Comment: This is incorrect.  For example, the automaton accepts the string 10.

Comment: Oh thanks... @saulspatz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not accounted for the strings which begin with $1$. In your notation:
$$
\{1^n0^{m+1}|m,n\in \mathbb N\}\cup\{1^n0^{m+1}1X|m,n\in \mathbb N,X\text{ non-empty}\}
$$
where $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2.\dots\}$. In regex notation,
$$
(1^*00^*|1^*00^*1(0|1)(0|1)^*)
$$

Answer (score 1):

A short regular expression for the language accepted by this DFA is 
$$
1^*0^+(\varepsilon \cup 1\{0,1\}^*).
$$

Answer (score 0):

The automaton accepts any string containing at least one $0.$  In the notation I am used to, I would write $\{0,1\}^*0\{0,1\}^*$ as a regular expression for the language. Here $\{0,1\}^*$ means any string of $0$'s and $1$'s, possibly empty.

In the notation you are using the answer would be something like $$
L=\{1^n0, 1^n0X| n = 0,1,2,\dots\}$$ 
That is, a (possibly empty) string of $1$'s, followed by a $0$, followed by anything.  If you have a notation (say Y) for a string that may be empty, then you can shorten it to $$
L=\{1^n0Y| n = 0,1,2,\dots\}$$

Comment: What about 01? It have one 0 but still cannot regconized

Comment: $L = \{1^n0^n, 1^n0^n1X, 0^n, 0^n1X | n = 1,2,3,....\}$ . I think this should be like this but it look pretty long...

Comment: No, this is not correct, either.  When you write $1^n0^n$ it means you have the same number of $1$'s and $0$'s.  I'll try to recast my answer in this style.

Comment: thanks @saulspatz , i think Mike Earnest answer below look pretty right!